# Split element into array with reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have some edges in a graph, which I get with:

```
const edges = getEdges();
```

Each edge has an array of labels, which I get with:

```
const edges = getEdges().map(function (edge, i) {
  return (i + 1) + '-' + getLabels(edge).sort().join('-');
});
```

So if I have 2 edges, each with two labels, I get an array

```
[
  '1-label1-label2',
  '2-label1-label2'
]
```

But what I want is

```
[
  '1-label1',
  '2-label2',
  '3-label1',
  '4-label2'
]
```

So I guess I need to use `Array.reduce()`.

Comment: What is the logic? Can we have an example of edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method do something like this.

```
const edges = getEdges().reduce(function(arr, edge) {
  return arr.concat(
    getLabels(edge)
    .sort()
    .map(function(v, i) {
      return (arr.length + i) + '-' + v;
    })
  );
}, []);
```

---

Using [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method instead of [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method.

```
const edges = getEdges().reduce(function(arr, edge) {
  [].push.apply(arr, getLabels(edge)
    .sort()
    .map(function(v, i) {
      return (arr.length + i) + '-' + v;
    })
  );
  return arr;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to me that either `map` or `reduce` is what you actually want, just a nested pair of `forEach` (although we could shoe-horn a `reduce` in if we wanted):

```
const edges = [];
getEdges().forEach(edge => {
  getLabels(edge).sort().forEach(label => {
    edges.push(`${(edges.length + 1)}-${label}`);
  });
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const getEdges = () =>
  [
    {labels: ['label2', 'label1']},
    {labels: ['label1', 'label2']}
  ];
const getLabels = edge => edge.labels;

const edges = [];
getEdges().forEach(edge => {
  getLabels(edge).sort().forEach(label => {
    edges.push(`${(edges.length + 1)}-${label}`);
  });
});
console.log(edges);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a reduce operation on the edges, which takes each edge and adds to a newly constructed array.

Using a forEach on the labels of each edge results in 1..n items, that will be added to this new array. Using the new array (result)'s current length can neatly solve the problem of naming the result item as desired (i.e. from 1 to N).

```
const res = getEdges().reduce(result, edge => {
  const labels = getLabels(edge).sort();
  labels.forEach(label => result.push(`${result.length + 1}-${label}`));
  return result;
}, []);
```

NOTE: this solution uses reduce and ES6 features, which is according to mentioned tags.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: added explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can first map the result of `getEdges` to `getLabels`, and then flatten the resulting array with [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and the spread syntax.

```js
const getEdges = () => ['a', 'b'];
const getLabels = () => ['label1', 'label2'];

const edges = [].concat(...getEdges().map(getLabels))
  .map((label, i) => `${i + 1}-label`);
console.log(edges);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` as below instead of `map` or `reduce`.

**Working snippet**: (ES6)

```js
const getEdges = () => [
     '1-label1-label2',
     '2-label1-label2'
   ];

const getLabels = (edge) => edge.split('-').sort();

let edges = [];

getEdges().forEach((edge) => {
  getLabels(edge).forEach((label) => {
    if(label.indexOf('label') > -1) {
       edges.push(edges.length + 1 + '-' + label);
    }
  });
});

console.log(edges);
```

**Working snippet**: (ES5)

```js
function getEdges() {
   return [
     '1-label1-label2',
     '2-label1-label2'
   ];
}

function getLabels(edge) {
  return edge.split('-').sort();
}

var edges = [];

getEdges().forEach(function (edge) {
  getLabels(edge).forEach(function (label) {
    if(label.indexOf('label') > -1) {
       edges.push(edges.length + 1 + '-' + label);
    }
  });
});

console.log(edges);
```